# D3JS Change TSV Data Column Ordering

Tags: d3.js

I've just draw a stacked-area-chart with D3JS.
[This is my referral implementation](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211)

I also need to dynamically swap the ordering of the layers.
I think that there isn't a way to do it dynamically without redrawing (or is there any? :D )

Actually i'm trying to map the data to a new header column, but this implies the redrawing.

Let me show you an example: 
Here is the TSV header ['date', 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC']
Every column, except of 'date', represent the % of area for that sample.

I would like to dynamically rearrange the area layers, but I'm pretty sure that I also need to parse again the data with a new header 
eg: ,

```
['date', 'columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC'] 
-map to-
['date','columnB', 'columnC', 'columnA']
```

and then draw the result.

I'm doing it right? Thanks for your support, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that defines the array that will be passed to the `stack()` function:

```
var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
```

Right now, this is the array:

```
["Google Chrome","Internet Explorer","Firefox","Safari","Microsoft Edge","Opera","Mozilla","Other/Unknown"]
```

But you can sort it anyway you want. For instance, sorting by alphabetic order:

```
keys.sort();
```

Which gives us:

```
["Firefox","Google Chrome","Internet Explorer","Microsoft Edge","Mozilla","Opera","Other/Unknown","Safari"]
```

Here is the result: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/6a339ed0731a70bb234af150ee6b4a99

Here is another one, with a random permutation (refresh the page to see diferent orders): https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/662f99901219b8907030ec3c84363f3a

Pay attention to this: the order in the stacked area chart is now different, but the colours don't keep the same for each browser (that is, each stacked area). That's because `d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)` assigns the colours in a *first-come, first served* basis.

Comment: Dear Gerardo, thanks for your answer. very interesting!
Yes i've noticed the color issue that you are reporting, i've solved using a custom color generator/manager. 

Anyway, correct me if i'm wrong, this trick always redraw the data right?

Comment: No, it simply changes the array. You'll have to draw the paths later. In D3, changing the data is just this: changing the data. Nothing changes in the DOM unless you order it.

Comment: Undestood! :) Thanks for your quick answer, and for the explanation